# Custom Admin CSS styles to style media uploader?

Tags: css, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

Hopefully a simple answer to this. Using the wp custom header feature, the media upload screen shows an extra field: "set as header". I'm trying to make this text bigger as it can easily be missed.

Firebug says it has a class of "a.wp-set-header". I can change the font size within firebug and it works, but adding this in my css doesn't do anything - any ideas? Thanks

```
a.wp-set-header{
font-size:22px !important;
font-weight:bold !important;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its likely that you're not enqueing your CSS file to be used in the admin area, however you did not say. Anyway, this is what you can do...

Place the following into your functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'my_admin_css' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_css' );

function my_admin_css(){
   if( is_admin() ) {
    wp_enqueue_style(
        "media_upload", 
        get_bloginfo('template_directory')."/css/custom_admin.css", 
        false, 
        false, 
        "all"
    );
   }
}
```

Where `../css/custom_admin.css` is an assumed directory and file in your theme folder.

You can learn more about the various methods to handle both scripts and CSS files for both the front end and admin starting with,

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

...the rest of which can be found under the miscellaneous functions section here

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference#Miscellaneous_Functions

...and you shall see related functions at the bottom of each individual function page like that of the above `wp_enqueue_style`.

Comment: That worked perfectly - thank you :-)

Still don't understand why I have to create a special css sheet and enque it just for this, but I will read your suggested links.

Comment: The reason is that, the stylesheet that you are using in your theme only gets applied to the front end, not the admin. That's why you need to tell WordPress "Hey I want you to queue up this file on the backend". Which by the way I've made an update to my code, so please adjust yours to reflect this change (using `is_admin()`). You can use your existing stylesheet in the example if you want but then you would be loading unnecessary styles into your admin area that could conflict. Its always best to separate your styles for logic and best practice purposes regardless of who its for.

Comment: FANTASTIC - Learning so much here, think I'm going to explode!
Thanks

Comment: No problem, the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Main_Page) is a great resource to begin with, you can get up to speed on many of the API functions as well as other WP based concepts. Although not the only resource, its a good starting point as a beginner (assuming you are?). Searching WPSE is also an even better idea too, the wealth found in answers here is unparalleled to that of any single site.  Any further questions you have along the way - just start a new thread. All the best.